# iOS how long does it take before going to deep sleep?

Tags: ios, sleep

I heard somewhere long ago that after you lock your iOS screen, it will go to a deep sleep mode after a certain period of time. In this mode, apps can no longer do anything or triggering an NSTimer. Is there any specific time duration before entering this deep sleep mode?

NOTE: guys, please don't just answer with links. Extract some information you found before putting them in here. It won't be hard if you know the answer is in those links, right?

Comment: @MSK It says 36 hours. BUT those are for iPod products, maybe it's not the same as other devices like iPhone/iPad ?

Comment: And that is why people shouldn't be posting links if they're not even going to bother reading them first.

Answer (score -3):

Look at the answer for the question below, i think it explains what you are looking for...

[NSTimer events do no occur when screen locked on iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198220/nstimer-events-do-no-occur-when-screen-locked-on-ios-5)

also take a look at this too...

[Is it possible to distinguish between locking the device and sending an app to background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754317/is-it-possible-to-distinguish-between-locking-the-device-and-sending-an-app-to-b)

> One solution, it would appear, is to play your sound when your timer
>   fires, and in the interim, play a silent sound continuously in order
>   to prevent the iPhone from sleeping. A hack, but at least in this case
>   not a completely ugly hack since using a sound in order to keep the
>   iPhone awake in order to play a sound has a kind of symmetry.

Comment: sadly it doesn't say anything about the time duration.

Comment: man... read the answer..! It also gives you a work around..:)

Comment: man... read the question..! I don't want the work around. I want the time! :(